# Django F() expression not working inside a function parameter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm trying to convert DateTime value with a specific timezone in a query, it worked when I explicitly added the timezone

```
InventoryDetails.objects.filter(Q(check_time=checktime.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata')))
```

But it's not working when I use the below F() expression

```
InventoryDetails.objects.filter(Q(check_time=checktime.astimezone(timezone(F('time_zone')))
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Django is simply a wrapper around SQL so any query you make with Django's object models and methods has to be eventually translated into a raw SQL query, which means all functions you wish to call in a query have to exist as a database function, not a client-side function.